# PHP auto convert price to 99 rather than 100

Tags: php, rounding

I have different prices:

```
100
550
799
1200
350
```

Wonder how i can automatically convert them to

```
99
549
799
1200
349
```

I'd just do -1, but some are already correct like 799, and i don't want it to be 798.

Cant think of way to do this conversion i am good with PHP but not great with math. I bet we need to find if it divides by 2 if yes then subtract 1 if not then do nothing.

```
if ($price % 2) {
   $price = intval($price) - 1;
}
```

Is this the best way to do it?

Comment: Is it only for the the 99 that you want to do this for?

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, for every number, is not %2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
if(($price % 10) == 0) {
    $price--;
}
```

Comment: because you only want to substract when the last digit is a 0 right? so than it is divisible by 10...

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this :

```
if (($price % 50) == 0)
{
    $price--;
}
```

Everytime the modulo of 50 will be equal to zero (this will be the case for any number that ends with "50" or "100"), it will remove one.

Change the second value (50 in this case) if you want to target more or less prices.

Answer (score 1):

As you don't want to have 798, your code does not work

But you can use this.

```
if ($price % 10) {
   $price = intval($price) - 1;
}

799 % 2 = 1
800 % 2 = 0
798 % 2 = 0

799 % 10 = 0
800 % 10 = 1
798 % 10 = 0
```

or %50 if you only want to subtract 1 from numbers like 750 and 800